# How to print the sql query executing in mybatis mapper xml to the console

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, orm, mybatis, ibatis

Suppose I am executing below query which is there in my mapper xml:

```
<select id="getData" parameterType="java.util.HashMap" resultType="java.util.LinkedHashMap">

select * from emp where empId=#{empId}          
    </select>
```

In the above xml empId is the dynamic value that returns the value from the key  of the HashMap that is passed as parameter in above mapper xml in Mybatis.

Is there any way to print the sql with the passed param to the console when the above select query mapped to method getData is ran.

for example I pass data empId =1
I want in console : select * from emp where empId=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add log4j.properties

```
log4j.logger.yourmapperpackage=DEBUG
```

and the sql debug is like this:

```
2016-01-09 20:51:10,621 DEBUG [com.xxxMapper.insert] - <==>  Preparing: INSERT INTO video_info (content, id, create_time, title, media_url, zhan_count, cover_url) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) >
2016-01-09 20:51:10,627 DEBUG [com.xxxMapper.insert] - <==> Parameters: vcontent(String), 0(Long), 2016-01-09 20:51:10.616(Timestamp), vtitle(String), null, 1(Integer), null>
2016-01-09 20:51:10,628 DEBUG [com.xxxMapper.insert] - <<==    Updates: 1>
```

Answer (score -1):

Look for "logback.xml" in your project...\resources\

Change mybatis log level to INFO

Comment: There is no logback.xml in my project.

Comment: I managed to set logger. It is printing db session objects but still not printing query.